# Open Graph data facebook

Tags: seo, metadata, facebook-opengraph, title

I have problem with title in facebook debugger!

After open html page static title is ex. stackoverflow.

After 2-3 second I get data from json and change tittle to www.stackoverflow.com

```
$(document).prop('title', 'www.stackoverflow.com');
```

In fb debugger og:title is stackoverflow, how set og:title = www.stackoverflow.com

I don't need put: `<meta property="og:title" content="www.stackoverflow.com" />`
content I get from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as Facebook probably won't execute any Javascript and wait for results. It's rather uncommon to make this part dynamic.